# codesign is unable to get entitlements

Tags: macos, codesign

I am running OS X 10.11.4 and I am trying to use `codesign` to extract the entitlements from executables. The manual page lists `--entitlements` as an option but it does nothing. I have tried `codesign --entitlements` and `codesign -dvvv --entitlements`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try `codesign -d -v --entitlements - "$BINARY_PATH"`